# boolean data type random integer

Tags: c, random, boolean

Im trying to create a random number generator and judging the random integers odd or even using a srand call and boolean but i cant figured out how to get it to distinguish properly between whats odd and whats even.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <time.h>

int i;
int num1;
int num2;

bool isOdd (int num1, int num2);

int main(void)
{
srand(time(NULL));


for (i=1; i <= 10; ++i) {
 num1 = rand() % 10 + 1;
 num2 = rand() % 10 + 1;
printf("The two random numbers are %u and %u\n", num1, num2);


bool valueIsOdd = isOdd(num1, num2);

if (valueIsOdd) {
    printf("one of these numbers, %u and %u, isOdd.\n\n", num1, num2);
}
else {
    printf("Both of these numbers, %u and %u, are even.\n\n", num1, num2);
    }
}
}

bool isOdd(int num1, int num2)
{
if (num1 % 2 != 0) {
    return true;
}
else {
    return false;
    }

}
```

Comment: What's supposed to happen with your program? For some example numbers, what is the expected output and what is the actual output? Please take some time to read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: Your printing doesn't explicitly cover the case where both numbers are odd.  You could say "At least one of these numbers is odd".  Or deal with it another way.

Comment: Note that your printf statements do not seem to handle the case in which both numbers are odd.

Comment: why pass two numbers to `isOdd()` when only one of them will be checked?

Answer (score 0):

You are only checking one number in the function `isOdd`. You need to check both numbers.

```
if ((num1 % 2 != 0) || (num2 %2 !=0)) {
   return true;
}
else {
   return false;
}
```

Or, you can check for both even and make the code a bit cleaner.

```
if ((num1 % 2 == 0) && (num2 %2 ==0)) {
   return false;
}
else {
   return true;
}
```

Comment: Or plain `return num1 % 2 != 0 || num1%2 !=0;`

Answer (score 0):

I understand your question.
u are asking that to differentiate from the two number which is odd right.
The main purpose of the bool is to represent either 1 or 0 why to use char consists of 8 bits.
If u want to check 1 number use bool datatype.
Otherwise if u want to know two number of all possible results better go with char datatype.

Here u have two numbers.4 possibility.

```
        number 1         number 2
1         odd              even
2         even             odd
3         even             even
4         odd              od


         if ((num1 % 2 != 0) && (num2 % 2 == 0)) {
                return 1;
         }
        else if ((num1 % 2 == 0) && (num2 % 2 != 0)) {
                return 2;
        }
        else if ((num1 % 2 == 0) && (num2 % 2 == 0)) {
                return 3;
        }
        else {
           return 4;
        }
```